# How to specify an entry for a book where no author is given

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm using `biblatex`. I want to store an entry in my `.bib` file that has the following semantics:

- It refers to a book as a whole
- The book contains articles from different authors
- The book itself has no author
- For citing, the editor is named
- It has to be distinguishable when citing, since the editor is stated with an added '(Hg.)' (That's German abbrevation for *'Herausgeber'* which would be editor) instead of the author.

How do I do this?

Comment: If there's an `editor` field but no `author` field for an entry of type `@book`, BibTeX and biblatex will happily use the information in the `editor` field for citations. To cite individual chapters in the book (possibly authored by persons other than the editor), you should entries of type `@inbook`, possibly using the `crossref` field to point to the entry of type `@book`; this will save you from having to repeat fields such as `year`, `publisher`, and so on.

Comment: Incollection?..

Comment: @Mico I am getting a "missing author" warning in Overleaf for a book with an editor field but no author. What gives?

Comment: @Mico I was (unwittingly) using a flawed .bst file which checked all fields for `author` and issued warnings everywhere. Thanks for yout input.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `@collection` entry seems to be exactly what you want.

The `biblatex` documentation says:

> A single-volume collection with multiple, self-contained contributions
>   by distinct authors which have their own title. The work as a whole has
>   no overall author but it will usually have an editor.

`@book` is not the most appropriate choice here because `biblatex` expects a `@book` to have an author.

The entries within that work can then be of type `@incollection` `crossref`ing back to the `@collection`.

The language file needs slight patching so we have `Hg.` and not `Hrsg.`. The format of the editor string can be changed from "Name, ed." to "Name (ed.)" with two more lines.

```
\documentclass[ngerman, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% everyone loves UTF-8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{WaContCont,
  author      = {Anna Wärnsby},
  title       = {On Controllability as a Contextual Variable},
  crossref    = {StEngMod},
  pages       = {69-98},
}

@collection{StEngMod,
  editor      = {Tsangalidis, Anastasios and Facchinetti, Roberta},
  title       = {Studies on English Modality},
  date        = {2009},
  location    = {Bern},
  publisher   = {Lang},
}
\end{filecontents}

% this is our language file with the new abbreviations for editor
\begin{filecontents}{ngerman-ed.lbx}
  \ProvidesFile{ngerman-ed.lbx}
  \InheritBibliographyExtras{ngerman}% extras are inherited from ngerman ...
  \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
    inherit          = {ngerman},% .... as well as all the keys
    editor           = {{Herausgeber}{Hg\adddot}},
    editors          = {{Herausgeber}{Hg\adddot}},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-ed}% use the new abbreviations

% editor string in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}% so editor is set in parentheses
% do not set the parentheses off with a comma
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\begin{document}
  The \verb|@collection| is \cite{StEngMod}, whereas \cite{WaContCont} is \verb|@incollection|.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example citations and bibliography from MWE above]

Answer (score 6):

`bibtex` as well as `biblatex` take the `editor` field if there is no `author` field given. With the `@inbook` and `@book` entry types you can easily distinguish between single chapters or essays within the book and the book itself.

Also the `crossref` mechanism of `biblatex` makes it very easy to reference from the `@inbook` to the `@book` entry. Therefore you don't have to enter all the book's information again for every `@inbook` entry which also reduces redundancy.

Compare the example below:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
editor= {Some Name},
title = {Random Title},
year = {2013},
}

@inbook{test2,
author= {Another Name},
title = {Some Essay},
crossref = {test}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. Unfortunately I can only select one as the accepted one and the other was a bit better IMHO.

Comment: @Scolytus No worries, I can deal with that ;-)

Comment: +1 because your answer shows a minimal, easy-to-understand configuration, but I would definitely agree with @moewe in that these entries should be a `@(in)collection` and not a `@(in)book` if the subportion has a distinct author. I might even suggest changing your answer because this change wouldn’t add any complexity.

Comment: @doncherry Reconsidering my answer I would agree with you. `@(in)collection` would be the better option.